# How do I make JS know about the application root?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have some javascript that's referencing `/jobs/GetIndex` in an MVC project.  This works great when I run it locally because I have a `Controller` called `JobsController`.  When I deploy it, I deploy the application to a 'Jobs' subfolder, which means the URL should become `http://site/jobs/jobs/GetIndex` but it's going to `http://site/jobs/GetIndex`, I presume because the javascript doesn't know what the 'root URL' is, and uses the site as the root.  How can I get it to work in both environments?

Comment: Are you using this server-side or client-side?  Do you use a packing tool like webpack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply care about getting the root/base url of the site so you can append that to get the other url you are after, you may simply use `/` as the first character of your url.

```
var urlToJobIndex2= "/jobs/GetIndex";
```

---

**Here is an alternate approach** if you want more than just the app root (Ex : Specific urls( built using mvc helper methods such as `Url.RouteUrl` etc)

You may use the `Url.Content` helper method in your razor view to generate the url to the app base, assign it to a javascript variable and use that in your other js code to build your other urls.
***Always make sure to use javascript namespacing when doing so to avoid possible issues with global javascript variables.***

If you want to get url to a specific action method, you may use the `Url.Action`  or `Url.RouteUrl` helper methods.

So in your razor view (*Layout file or specific vie*w), you may do this.

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};  
    myApp.Urls = myApp.Urls || {};
    myApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
    myApp.Urls.jobIndexUrl= '@Url.Action("GetIndex","jobs")';
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

And in your `PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js` file, you can read it like

```
var urlToJobIndex= myApp.Urls.jobIndexUrl;
// Or With the base url, you may safely add the remaining url route.
var urlToJobIndex2= myApp.Urls.baseUrl+"jobs/GetIndex";
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342953/40521) is a detailed answer about the same , but using this in a specific page/view

**Angular Js**

You might need the correct relative url(s) in your angular controller / services / directives.The same approach will work for your angular code as well. Simply build the js namespace object and use the angular `value` provider to pass the data to your angular controllers/services/directives as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427447/angularjs-directive-templateurl-doesnt-work-while-template-works/34427511#34427511) in detail with example code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="/jobs">` to your head tag. It will specify the root.

This is further explained here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: Would this not change the URL to be incorrect when I'm running locally?