# Different behaviour posting to controller via javascript than directly from submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this button in a form:

```
<button id="save" type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("SaveEvent")" formmethod="post">Save</button>
```

Which posts to this controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveEventAsync(EventDataModel vm)
{
    // save to db etc...
    TempData["Saved"] = true;
    return RedirectToActionWithReturnUrl("EventDetail", new { eventId = vm.EventId });
}
```

This redirects me fine to the detail page. But if I then add this JS function to do the post, I don't get redirected nor do I see the value in TempData.

```
$('#save').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( "SaveEvent", {
        EventID: "@Model.EventId",
        SomeValue: 123
    });
}
```

I tried redirecting in the JS function but it doesn't return me the newly saved values:

```
window.location = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("EventDetail", new { eventId = @Model.EventId}))';
```

Could someone please explain why the redirect in the controller does not work when posting from JS?

Comment: Never heard of `RedirectToActionWithReturnUrl` method ! Is that your custom method ? What it does ?

Comment: It could be because your SaveEventAsync is expecting an object of type EventDataModel which you are not passing to it.

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: You cannot return `RedirectResult` in ajax request

Comment: Yes, ReturnToActionWithReturnUrl is a custom method which simply adds a URL to the RouteValues. Not sure why as I didn't write it :-).  I understand now that RedirectResult cannot be returned to an ajax request. Thanks to Shyju for the code sample. Works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redirect related methods in controller *(`Redirect`,`RedirectToAction` etc*) returns a 302 response with the new url to be redirected to as the value of the `location` header and browsers will usually issue a new GET request to that.

You should not be making the call to an action method which returns a 302 response from an ajax call. Instead, you should return a json response to the ajax call which is making the request.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveEventAsync(EventDataModel vm)
{
    // save to db etc...  
    return Json(new {status = "success"});    
}
```

and in your `$.post` method callback, inspect the response and do the redirection.

```
$('#save').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var url="@Url.Action("SaveEvent","YourControllerName")";

    $.post(url, { EventID: "@Model.EventId", SomeValue: 123 }, function(res){
        if (res.status === "success") {
           window.location.href =" @Url.Action("EventDetail","YourControllerName",
                                                          new { eventId=Model.EventId })";
        }
    });

});
```

I updated your code to use Url.Action method to build the correct relative url to the action method(s). If you javascript code is inside a separate js file, build the base url in your razor page and pass to your js code as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sample. My code works fine with this.