# absolute path on call ajax mvc4 c#

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a project in mvc 4 entity framework and call the controller method with ajax.
My problem is when i am using my app local, url is "Controller/Method" but when i publish i have to change url to "http://domain/appName/Controller/Method"

who can i do to get absolute path on ajax url??? my ajax is on js file and i can't use function like html.actionlink

example:

```
$("#btnAnswer").click(function () {

            $.ajax({

                url: "http://domain/appName/Controller/method/",
                //url: "/Controller/method/",
                data: { answer: $("#answer").val(), question_id: $("#question_id").val(), answer_id: $("#answer_id").val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);

                }

            }).error(function () {

            }).fail(function () {

            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using this in a js file you can do something like this:

```
$("#btnAnswer").click(function () {

                var hostString = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + /";

                $.ajax({

                    url: hostString + "/appName/Controller/method/",
                    //url: "/Controller/method/",
                    data: { answer: $("#answer").val(), question_id: $("#question_id").val(), answer_id: $("#answer_id").val() },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);

                    }

                }).error(function () {

                }).fail(function () {

                });

        });
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need the absolute url. Correct relative url is fine.

You should use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative path to your action method. This will generated the proper path irrespective of your current page/view.

```
url: "@Url.Action("ActionMethodName","YourControllerName")"
```

`Url.Action` helper method will work if your javascript code is inside a razor view. But if your code is inside an external js file, you should build the relative url to your app root using `Url.Content("~")` helper method and pass that to your js code via a variable as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168) . Try to use javascript namespacing when doing so to prevent possible conflict/overwriting from other global variables with same name.

**EDIT :** *Including Marko's comment as an alternate solution. Thank you :)*

If it is an anchor tag, you can simply use the `href` attribute value of the clicked link.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete","Product")" class="ajaxLink">Delete</a>
```

and in your js code

```
$("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   //use url variable value for the ajax call now.

});
```

If it is any other type of html element, you can use html5 data attribute to keep the target url and use the jQuery data method to retrieve it in your js code.

```
<div data-url="@Url.Action("Delete","Product")" class="ajaxLink">Delete</div>
```

and in your js code

```
$(".ajaxLink").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault(); // to be safe
   var url = $(this).data("url");
   //use url variable value for the ajax call now.

});
```

Comment: To expand on this, in the razor code where you rended the btnAnswer button add data-url-location="@Url.Action("ActionMethodName","YourControllerName")" and in your javascript external file simply read the $("#btnAnswer").data('url-location') this will provide you the correct url.

Comment: Thanks @Marko. That is an excellent alternate solution. I added it to the answer ( with proper attribution :) )for future readers. Let me know if that is a problem.