# Pass DateTime to Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to pass DateTime that was selected in datetimepicker in controller.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetData(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Use Ajax?
How to do it correct?

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/GetData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(????),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) { }, 
    failure: function (r, e, s) { alert(e); } 
 });
```

Comment: When do you want to send the data?

Comment: Maybe it will be better to send datetime in controller when span is closing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like the way you put all this JS and CSS on the page.. anyway this should works.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({useCurrent: false});
            $('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change",function(e){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetData",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {nameOfVar: $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').date().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')},
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(result){ alert('Done') }, 
                    error: function(r,e,s){ alert(e) } 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: which kind of var do you expect? sure json?

Comment: public ActionResult GetData(string dateTime) get's null. I expect on DateTime or something that can describe date.

Comment: **...data('DateTimePicker').date()** returns an object. I saw it on the console right now, please, try using:
`data: {yourVarName: JSON.stringify($('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').date())},`

Comment: Yes! It work's! But Controller get's object how can i get datetime from object?

Answer (score 0):

You can basically listen for the `change` event on the input field and send the value of that. You don't really need to stringify it as it is simple value you are sending.

```
$(function(){

  $("#datetimepicker1").change(function(){
     var v = $(this).val();
     if(v.length>0)
     {
          var url = "@Url.Action("GetData","Home")" +"? dateTime="+v;
          $.get(url, function(re) {
              //do something with the re
              console.log(re);
          });
     }

  });


});
```

I used the `Url.Action` method to generate the correct relative url to the action method. This code will work if your js code is inside a razor view. If your code is inside an external js file, Use the method explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).

Answer (score 0):

I only did this and it works for me

```
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" });
```