# ASP.NET: How to get from Dropdownlist to Autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist and want to turn it into autocomplete using jquery.

The dropdown looks like this and works:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Name", Model.CategoryID), "Categories", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I also added an autocomplete field using jquery that works. But so far I can only populate it with dummy data:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp"
    ];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags 
    });
});
```

How can I populate my dropdown field with the data that is available in the dropdown?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry ! What is your question ? you want to populate the autocomplete text box with data from list of categories ? Did you try the remote data source example ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Right now I have the dropdown, but I want to replace it with an autocomplete text box. The underlying data should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `source` as an action method which returns data you want to show as autocomplete option in JSON format.

```
$(function(){

    $("#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: "@Url.Action("SearchCategories","Home")",
      minLength: 1,
      select: function (event, ui) {

        //If you want to do something on the select event, you may do it here
        //$("#tags").html(ui.item.label);
      }
    });

})
```

Make sure you have an action method called `SearchCategories` in your HomeController which returns the data you want.

```
public ActionResult SearchCategories(string term)
{
    var db= new MyDbContext();
    var results = db.Categories.Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith(term))
                                       .Select(x=>new {  id =x.Id, 
                                                         label =x.Name }).ToList();
    return Json(results,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This should enable the autocomplete on an input with id `tags`,assuming you have jQuery ui library(and it's dependencies) loaded properly in your page and you do not have any other script errors in your page.  I have used `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative url to the action method. It will work fine if your js code is inside a razor view. But if your code is inside an external js file, you should follow the approach described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. At first I was hoping that I could just pass the whole list to the view, but your method works exactly how I want it and is more flexible than passing the whole list.

Comment: hi, if possible can you answer issue i am facing in asp mvc cache , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704618/asp-mvc-caching-static-contents-gives-500-internal-server-error) is the question. Any help would be great.