# Updating .NET Charts using ajax.beginform

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm using .NET Charts to create some dynamic charts from a table in a database, and each chart is a separate view, with a corresponding action in the controller.

Then they are displayed in a main view as images:

```
<img src="~/Controller/Chart1" class="centered" />
```

Now I want to be able to filter the charts by date, and I've added the parameters to the actions and a couple datepickers for a start date and an end date.

I'm trying to refresh the charts using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), but I'm having trouble. Without Ajax, the filter works, but redirects to a page containing just the updated chart.

With Ajax, nothing happens, or rather, if I set the UpdateTargetId to a div it gets filled with text, like byte code or something.
This is what I'm using:

```
<div>
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("Chart1", "controller",
         new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "Chart1"
        }))
    {
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="begindate" class="datefield" placeholder="Begin Date" />
        <input type="text" name="enddate" class="datefield" placeholder="End Date" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>

    <img src="~/controller/Chart1" class="centered" />
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the dates to your action method and let the action method uses these dates to generate a filtered data set which will be used to generate the chart.

You can simply use jQuery Ajax to do this.

```
<div>
     <input type="text" name="begindate" class="datefield" placehold="Begin Date" />
     <input type="text" name="enddate" class="datefield" placeholder="End Date" />
     <input type="submit" id="btnFilter" value="Filter" />
     <img src="~/controller/Chart1" id="chartImg" class="centered" />
</div>
```

Now when user clicks the form, pass the dates

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnFilter").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var d1 = $("input[name='begindate']").val();
    var d2 = $("input[name='enddate']").val();
    var url = "@Url.Action("Chart1", "YourControllerName")";
    url += "?beginDate=" + d1 + "&endDate=" + d2;
    $("#chartImg").attr("src", url);
  });
});
```

Now of course your action method should accept the dates and return the data as needed:

```
public ActionResult Chart1(DateTime beginDate,DateTime endDate)
{
  // Return the chart image
}
```

I am using the Url.Action action method to generate the correct path to the Chart1 action method. This code will work if your JavaScript code is inside a [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) view. If your code is inside an external js file, Use the approach mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168)

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply. It worked wonderfully.
Just needed to add a horrible hack to convert the date format:

    var dateAr = d1.split('-');
    var newBDate = dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[0].slice(-2);