# JavaScript file returns 404 Not Found on IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

Now I know there are a few questions around with the same problem but I cannot find a solution, bearing in mind I'm fairly new to JavaScript and/or IIS.

So I have some Java script in an MVC app that when run locally via the Visual Studio IIS express, works a treat with no problems. I also have an IIS site that I have published with exactly the same code. Everything works fine apart from the JavaScript. I am including my script in a Razor view like so:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the following JavaScript is what I am trying to run.

```
<script>
function executeQuery() {
    var url = "/Application/CheckMobileResponse";
    debugger;


    $.get(url, { applicationId: @Model.ApplicationId, userId : @Model.UserId }, function(response) {
        debugger;
        //doing some stuff

    });
    setTimeout(executeQuery, 3000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(executeQuery, 3000);
});
```

Basically I am calling an action every 3 seconds and depending on the response I am using window.location.href to redirect to a new view.

I am quite confused because in the console window on google chrome I am getting a 404 server response Error as follows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) jquery-1.10.2.js:8720
>
> GET
> http://localhost/Application/CheckMobileResponse?applicationId=1&userId=5
> 404 (Not Found)

This to me looks like it is finding the jQuery file so may not be a case of not being able to load the JavaScript file. But it is instead failing because it cannot find my action on the GET request (which is odd because this works perfectly on Visual Studio IIS Express).

Comment: what is your site's base url ?

Comment: localhost/AppDashboard?

Comment: Most likely it is a security issue, your web.config might not be allowing the retrieval of `.js` file extension content from the `scripts` folder. Alternatively check your IIS folder where you published your project and make sure the script actually exists on disk.

Comment: A 404 error has nothing to do with client-side code.  If the AJAX request is being made then the JavaScript *is* clearly working.  A 404 means that the URL doesn't exist.  Should it?

Comment: Ah okay david, so the 404 means my javascript is definately working. And yes the URL should exist

Answer (score 3):

404 error means, the url you are trying to access does not exist/not found!

From your comment, your site's base name is `localhost/AppDashboard` .But when your run your code, It is trying to make a call to  `http://localhost/Application/CheckMobileResponse`. It is missing the **AppDashboard** ! part in the url.

You should not be hardcoding the path to your action method like that. Always try to use `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct url to the action methods. This way, your code will work (will generate the proper url(s)) irrespective of what page/path your user is currently in.

```
 var url = "@Url.Action("CheckMobileResponse","Application")";
```

When the page renders, razor will execute the `Url.Action` method and generate the url. So if you put the above code inside a razor view it will work. But if your js code is inside an external js file, Follow the solution explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).

Comment: Absolute life saver , thankyou... This is making me feel stupid because I have read alot that Url helpers are a must in order to avoid problems such as this. Thankyou again