# Set an url globally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC application, we call web service and web API methods from JavaScript files. Whenever the url gets changed, we have to modify the url in many .js files.

As we access the url in JavaScript, is there anyway to set it globally like web.config in .NET?

Thanks.

Comment: well you could have api for url retrieval, so you'd only have to set it on server, and it's not specific what url are you pointing to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have this or something similar in your view:

```
<script>
  window.apiUrl = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"]%>';
</script>
```

(or if it's Razor?...)

```
<script>
  window.apiUrl = '@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"])';
</script>
```

That way, your other scripts can simply reference:

```
var url = window.apiUrl;
```

Comment: Works, Thanks. I used,

<script>
    var varName= '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appKey"]';
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global variable in the view(call VewBag in the Controller),and This variable in the configuration