# jsonresult is returning html not json

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I published an ASP.NET MVC application to Godaddy. I'm having an issue with an Ajax call that is supposed to return a JSON object it returns the HTML of my site's index page. I previously had a problem with the app's menu bar links, where they were redirecting to my site's main page. I was able to solve the problem by adding a rule to my site's web.config that excluded the subfolder containing the app: `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(codesnippetapp)" negate="true" />`I checked the dev console in Chrome and the request URL is wrong. The URL should be http://www.mattdailey.net/codesnippetapp/Home/GetCodeData instead it is http://www.mattdailey.net/Home/GetCodeData

Here is the Ajax call and the JsonResult functions that retrieve the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetCodeData',
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedSnippetID),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $("#snippetcode").val(data.snippetCode);                    
                } else {
                    alert('invalid ID' + data.success);
                }
            }
        });
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCodeData(int snippetID)
    {

        CodeSnippet returnedsnippet = db.CodeSnippets.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == snippetID);
        if (returnedsnippet != null)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, snippetCode = returnedsnippet.SnippetCode });
        }
        return Json(new { success = false });

    }
```

What do I need to add to my app's web.config? Or do I need to add code to my site's web.config?

UPDATE:
I tried using the GET method but got an internal server error. I moved the script from an external file into the View itself by using the razor @section code like this:

```
@section Scripts 
{
... jQuery code
}
```

Then added this to the _Layout.cshtml:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

I did add the razor @Url.Action helper to the Ajax url. I also changed the way I publish the application to Godaddy, which I think helped too. I changed from the FTP method to Filesystem. I then uploaded the files manually via FTP. It's now working.

Thanks everyone for the help. I wrote out my steps hoping this will help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` at the beginning of the url value will make it as the root of your site (*not your app under that*).

Use `Url.Action` helper method to generate the path to your action method.

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetCodeData","Home")',
```

This should work if your javascript is inside a razor view. If your code is inside an external js file, call this method in a razor view and assign it to a variable and use it in your js file as explained in the second part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root)

Answer (score 0):

use **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet**

```
public JsonResult GetCodeData(int snippetID)
{

    CodeSnippet returnedsnippet = db.CodeSnippets.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == snippetID);
    if (returnedsnippet != null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, snippetCode = returnedsnippet.SnippetCode },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(new { success = false },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: You do not need to specify `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet` for an **HttpPost** action/call (which the OP is doing). It is needed only if you are returning some json from an GET action method.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a GET operation as you are trying to return Json to the client.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetCodeData',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedSnippetID),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $("#snippetcode").val(data.snippetCode);                    
                } else {
                    alert('invalid ID' + data.success);
                }
            }
        });

    public JsonResult GetCodeData(int snippetID)
    {

        CodeSnippet returnedsnippet = db.CodeSnippets.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == snippetID);
        if (returnedsnippet != null)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, snippetCode = returnedsnippet.SnippetCode }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```