# In MVC 4, how does one post/Call and action on the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to invoke an action on a controller when changing the value in a DatePicker. Whenever the javascript runs the 'requestDate' parameter is null. Thank you , in advance for your expertise.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSummaryByDate(string requestDate)
{
    return View(_acctSummary);
}
```

View

```
<form  name= "SummaryForm" method="post" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                Date
                <input id="DateQry" type="text" class="datepicker" >style="width:70px" name="requestDate"  >        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Partial

```
@Html.Partial("_SummaryList", @Model)
```

Javascript

```
$('.datepicker').on('change', function (e) {
    $.post('AcctSummary/GetSummaryByDate', {'string':e.date});
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `e.date` has a value?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your input type to date (currently you have set it to text)
2. Pass the 'value' property (e.value) to your controller

Comment: This may or may not be correct. There is no need to setup the input to date if using a datepicker, in fact, that may cause the datepicker to not work. `e.value` will not necessarily have the date in it either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are sending the date value with the same parameter name as of your action method parameter name. Also you can use `$(this).val()` to get the current value of the input.

Your action method parameter name is `requestDate`. So let's use the same when we send data.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();  //enable date picker

$('.datepicker').on('change', function (e) {
  $.post('AcctSummary/GetSummaryByDate', { requestDate : $(this).val()},function(res){
      // do something with the response
      console.log(res);
  });
});
```

You might also consider using the `Url.Action` html helper method to build the correct relative url to the action method instead of hardcoding it.

So in your razor view,

```
<script>
  var summaryUrl = "@Url.Action("GetSummaryByDate","AcctSummary")";
  // use this in your following js code
</script>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168) is a detailed post about passing these url's generated by html helper methods to your javascript code.

Comment: Shyju - When the parameter names matches, it worked. Thank you very much. The @Url.Action method did not work for me, because in my testing, it would only response to Click event like in a button and not Change events. I am a new to StackOverflow. Do I need to close this question and is this the way to thank you?

Comment: Url.Action is a server method and it should generate the correct url. I do not know what you mean by "only response to click event". BTW, If the answer helped, you can upvote/& mark this as answer (check the tick mark next to votes), I guess that is the way to thank people who helps you :) Thanks