# how to select User to Select based on country using mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables one is country table another one is doctor table both contains  country fields.if i select any country name from country based on the country name i want to display doctors name from the doctor table.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Country</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("CountryID", null, "--- Select Country ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.CountryID, null, new { @style = "color: red" })
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="exampleInput">Doctor Name</label>
                                <select id="UserRefID" class="select2-arrow"></select>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.UserRefID, null, new { @style = "color: red" })
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
```

Country bind Code:

```
#region Country
        public void Country_Bind()
        {
            userType type = new userType();
            DataSet ds = type.Get_Country();
            List<SelectListItem> coutrylist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                coutrylist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["CountryName"].ToString(), Value = dr["CountryID"].ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.CountryID = coutrylist;
        }
        #endregion
```

DAL :

```
public DataSet Get_Country()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Country", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

Doctor Bind based one country ID

#region Doctor Bind

```
    public JsonResult Company_Bind(string CountryID)
    {
        userType type = new userType();
        DataSet ds = type.Get_Doctor(CountryID);
        List<SelectListItem> Doctorlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Doctorlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["Tittle"].ToString() + " " + dr["DoctorName"].ToString(), Value = dr["DoctorID"].ToString() });
        }
        return Json(Doctorlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    #endregion

public DataSet Get_Doctor(string CountryID)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from DoctorRegistration where Country=@Country", con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", CountryID);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CountryID").change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#UserRefID").empty();
                $.get("Company_Bind", { CountryID: id }, function (data) {
                    var v = "<option>--- Select State ---</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                        v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#UserRefID").html(v);
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

[image: Doctor Table]

[image: Country]

If i use `[Authorize]` i cann't use ajax function

```
 //[Authorize]
    //[InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            UserType_Bind();
            Country_Bind();
            //Doctor_Bind();
            return View();
        }
```

if i don't use `[Authorize]` working fine

Comment: What is the issue ? Looks like you are making an ajax call to get the data

Comment: Doctor Name is not enabled @Shyju

Comment: You mean, you are getting the SELECT list populated, but the control is DISABLED ?

Comment: Yes correct country value is listed but based on country id doctor name is not displayed @Shyju

Comment: can you please also post the response you might be getting while making ajax call to get doctors. this will be available in the browsers console>Network tab (in case of chrome)

Comment: Not displayed and not populated are 2 different things ! You need to clearly specify what is happening right now and what is your expected behavior. Your code looks fine. Check whether you have any script errors in the page

Comment: Country ID doesn't passed to the controller Company_Bind..@Shyju

Comment: Country ID doesn't passed to the controller Company_Bind.@ParvSharma

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found @Shyju jquery.min.js" file

Comment: That means your page does not have jQuery loaded. Fix that. You need to include jquery library to use `$`

Comment: i solved that issues but i have one doubt above i added the code please check it and tell me what was my fault?@Shyju

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string `Company_Bind` as the url for the ajax call. So it will be appended to the current pages url and a call will be made to that.

For example, if your currrent page is `yourBaseUrl/Home/Index`, the call will be made to `yourBaseUrl/Home/index/Company_Bind?CountryID=4`

If your current page is `yourBaseUrl/Doctors/List`, the call will be made to `yourBaseUrl/Doctors/List/Company_Bind?CountryID=4`

This will give you **404** response as that is invalid url to your action method.

You should consider using the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative path to the action  method, irrespective of your current page.

So if your javascript code was inside a razor view,you can directly use it like

```
$.get("@Url.Action("Company_Bind")", { CountryID: id }, function (data) {

});
```

Or use the `Url.Action` overload which accepts the action method name and controller name.

```
$.get("@Url.Action("Company_Bind","Doctors")", { CountryID: id }, function (data) {

});
```

If it is in an external js file, you can still use the Url.Action helper in the razor view to generate the url and pass it to the external js file as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).