# Json array is null when received in controller

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

```
function viewReports(firstDate, lastDate) {
    var selected = $('#ReportSelected').find(":selected");
    var controller = "PortalReports";
    var method = "GetReport";

    var urlAjax = $("#basePath").val() + controller + "/" + method;
    var companydropdown = $('#ReportSelected :selected').data("companydropdown");
    var agencydropdown = $('#ReportSelected :selected').data("agencydropdown");
    var userdropdown = $('#ReportSelected :selected').data("userdropdown");

    var data = 
        {
            reportSelected: selected.text(),
            firstDate: firstDate,
            lastDate: lastDate,
            companydropdown: companydropdown,
            agencydropdown: agencydropdown,
            userdropdown: userdropdown
        };
    /*var data =
        [{
            "reportSelected": selected.text(),
            "firstDate": firstDate,
            "lastDate": lastDate,
            "companydropdown": companydropdown,
            "agencydropdown": agencydropdown,
            "userdropdown": userdropdown
        }];*/

    var answer = JSON.stringify({ data });

    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ data }),
        url: urlAjax,

        success: function (response) {
            loadReport(response);
        },
        error: function (ob, errStr) {
            alert("An error occured. Please try again.");
        }
    });

//Mvc
     public JsonResult GetReport(JArray data)
            {
           var persons = data.Select(x => x.ToObject<InputJson>());
```

JArray data is always null irrespective of how many ways I add square brackets of remove quotation marks etc, what am I doing wrong!!!
Prefer simple Object returned in array for readability as I might need to add to it.

Comment: Show you model for `JArray` (note you sending an object, not an array). If it contains properties `reportSelected`, `firstDate` etc, then it will be correctly bound if you use  `data: data` (no `JSON.stringify()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending a complex data structure(array), you should specify the `contentType` property when making ajax call. Specify the value of contentType property as `"application/json"`

```
//Values hard coded, you may replace with real values from your form.

var dataArray =    [{
                     reportSelected:'201501',
                     firstDate: '11/12/2010',
                     lastDate: '12/12/2010',
                     companydropdown: 4,
                     agencydropdown: 6,
                     userdropdown: 16,
                   }];

var urlAjax = "/Home/GetReport"; // Hard coded for demo. Read further..
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
    url: urlAjax,

    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (ob, errStr) {
        alert("An error occured. Please try again.");
    }
});
```

I suggest you create a view model /DTO to represent the data you are sending and use that in your action method.

```
public class ReportRequest
{
    public string reportSelected { get; set; }
    public DateTime firstDate { get; set; }
    public int companydropdown { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetReport(IEnumerable<ReportRequest> data)
{
   //do something with data 
   // to do : Return something
}
```

In the example, I hardcoded the value of urlAjax variable. You may consider using the html helper methods to generate the correct relative url path to the action method(s) as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342953/40521).